# Map view set according to distance

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am a new android developer. I am creating a map view application Where I want to set up my map view according distance from my current location. I have three buttons such as 100m,500m and 1 Km . When application is started then mapview will appear and current location is the center of the map. When i tap on 1 km then the map view is set up 1 km  according to current location. How can i do this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compute 1km in latitude and longitude, set the center to your current position ( I guess you succed to do that) and set the span to your MapController:

```
mController.zoomToSpan((int) spanLat,(int) spanLon);
```

> **zoomToSpan**
>        public void zoomToSpan(int latSpanE6,int lonSpanE6)
>
> Attempts to adjust the zoom of the map
>   so that the given span of latitude and
>   longitude will be displayed. Because
>   the zoom can only achieve discrete
>   levels, and because the aspect ratio
>   of the map may not match the ratio
>   given, the quality of the fit may
>   vary. The only thing we guarantee is
>   that, after the zoom, at least one of
>   the new latitude or the new longitude
>   will be within a factor of 2 from the
>   corresponding parameter.